# search a unique code from multiple table c#

Tags: c#, sql, database, datagridview

sorry my English is not perfect ...

I'm developing a utility to perform an inventory of products for a management program of a supermarket.
the software company has provided me with all the information needed to develop this tool because it no longer supports the program.
So I will work with existing data and tables.

I have 3 tables that contain the necessary data:

1. ProductList- that contains:
   ProductCode, Description
2. Warehouse - which contains:
   ProductCode, InitialStock, CurrentStock, MinimumStock, ReorderQuantities, Modified
3. RegistryCodesAdditionalArticles - which contains:
   ProductCode, Barcode

I've created 7 textbox that will contain:

Barcode,
ProductCode,
Description,
InitialStock,
CurrentStock,
MinimumStock,
ReorderQuantities.

the search must be performed by barcode and populate the textbox with other values required

the datagridview will be hidden

I load 3 datagridview with the following code:

```
        SqlCommand select1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT ProductCode,Description FROM ProductList ORDER BY ProductList ASC", connav);
        SqlDataAdapter find1 = new SqlDataAdapter(select1);
        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
        find1.Fill(dt1);

        BindingSource bs1 = new BindingSource();
        bs1.DataSource = dt1;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bs1;
```

etc...

please help me to overcome the problem

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

You just need simple inner joins here. why you are not passing barcode in your query?

Query should look like :

```
SELECT RCAA.Barcode,RCAA.ProductCode,PL.Description,W.InitialStock,W.CurrentStock,W.MinimumStock,W.ReorderQuantities
FROM RegistryCodesAdditionalArticles RCAA
JOIN Warehouse W
ON RCAA.ProductCode=W.ProductCode
JOIN ProductList PL
ON RCAA.ProductCode=PL.ProductCode
WHERE RCAA.Barcode = ':BARCODE FROM YOUR CODE'
```